# Is it possible to set a fix point in a multiple linear regression with fitlm for one specific variable in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I'm doing a multiple linear regression in Matlab with the function fitlm which looks basically like this:

```
model = fitlm(data,'Y ~ x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x4','RobustOpts','off','Weights',w)
```

The predictors are categorical AND double. Now I know that if x3 == 0, then Y == 0. x3 and Y are both double. Is it possible to add this information to the regression model? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: This is mathematically impossible. Either `x1*x2` and `x4` are linearly dependent on `x3`, in which case the regression is underdetermined, or, given a set of values which result in `Y==0` then any change in value of `x1*x2` or `x4` while `x3` remains `0` will result in nonzero `Y`. Unless those terms have zero-coefficients, in which case you just have `Y ~ x1*x3` with no intercept.

Comment: @Will You are totally right, thank you! With this information, all predictors are then linearly dependent on `x3`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to incorporate your knowledge that y=0 when x3=0 into the linear model, because it is inconsistent with the linear model. You can incorporate your knowledge by making a nonlinear model and fitting it, but you won't be able to use fitlm() to fit the nonlinear model. The nonlinear model could be done with the function below, where `p` is the vector of parameters which we want to estimate:

```
%function declaration: predictive model 
function f = yPred(p)
global x1, x2, x3
if x3=0
    f=0;
else
    f=p(1)*x1*x2 + p(2)*x1*x3 + p(3)*x4+ p(4);
end
end
```

After initializing the known data (y, x1, x2, x3, and w), define an error function, also known as objective function.  A common error function is the weighted sum of squared errors between the predicted y and actual y values.

```
% objective function = weighted sum squared error
objective = @(p) sum(w.*(y - yPred(p)).^2));
```

Then use `fmincon()` (see Matlab documentation) to estimate the unknown p. fmincon() finds the values `pEst` that minimize the objective function. You need to provide `fmincon()` with an initial guess for `pEst`.

```
pInit=[1 1 1 1];                          %initial guess
[pEst, wSSE] = fmincon(objective,pInit);  %pEst=estimate of p
                          %wSSE=value of the objective function at the minimum
```

It is a good idea when using fmincon() to try various initial guesses for pInit, in case the error surface has local minima that are not global minima.

Comment: Having a non-linear regression is due to complexity not yet considered, but I will keep your ansatz in mind for future implementations, thank you!